# ArcGIS Web AppBuilder View Query Results in AttributeTable

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm building a couple of custom widgets for use on a Web AppBuilder app that do some queries against feature layers. I get back a feature set, which I can convert to a local feature layer. What I'd like to be able to do is display that feature layer in the Attribute Table, so that I don't have to build a separate table to display query results. Unfortunately, it looks like using the addNewLayerTab call of the AttributeTable widget tries to query the feature layer with a where clause of "1=1". This causes an error, because queries on local feature layers cannot contain a where clause. Does anybody know of a way to hook this up properly?